# How would I replace all underscores in HTML tag IDs & classes with a hyphen?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I have written some bad CSS class & id names with underscores instead of hyphens. I’m trying to change all underscores to hyphens with sublime text replace feature (ctrl + H). How would I change underscores to hyphens in my HTML template only for id and class names?

From this:

```
<div id=“contact_container”></div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="contact-container"></div>
```

Comment: Are you limited to Sublime for doing this edit?

Comment: Note that you have invalid quotation marks up there. Don't use word processors for code editing.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the `sublimetext3` tag deletion since we can flag for "seeking recommendation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize Regex in your search. Regex is a way to create "rules" for the search. You'll be able to tell the search, "find everything that starts with 'id=' and has a '-' in it," for example.

Since I don't know how the rest of your code looks I can't tell you exactly what your Regex expression should be but [this article on using Regex in Sublime](https://softhints.com/sublime-3-regex-search-and-replace-examples/) might be a helpful starting point.

Comment: `ctrl` + `H` for "find & replace", `ctrl` + `shift` + `F` for "Find, Where (path) & replace"

Comment: Cool. Another nitpick: "Regex expression" is a bit redundant, no? "Regular expression expression"? :)

Comment: I've come up with this so far (?<=class=")[^"]* The only problem is I can't seem to replace specific characters between this Regex find. If anyone knows how to change a specific character withing a Regex find it would be really helpful. I'm looking to change all underscores with a hyphen.